# Facebook like Image gallery style

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I am looking to work on a gallery where i have to show category of Albums with snapshot of album icon inside each Album Category container.

Below image is for different layout for image inside each Category container. This is something similar to Facebook.

[image]

I need to show maximum of four album icons/image & minimum of 3 images in each Album category Container. I have been looking for similar example to but couldn't fined much on internet.

I have setup an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpmEmR). for each album i have to show the default image and on top of that i have to create the grid.

But image grid has to be in collage  style grid of minimum 3 or 4 images if we show 3 image then image on left or right show be 100in height to occupy the container height and other two image will be normal height.

I tried few thing but am not able to get it right.

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
  <!--item-->

  <li>
    <a href="albums/6/crisis-relief">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album One </h3>

      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album Two </h3>

      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="albums/5/health">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album Three </h3>

      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album Four </h3>

      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div style="position: absolute; height: auto; display: block; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block ! important; float: left ! important;" src="http://theologymix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/mountains-600x400.jpg">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block ! important; float: left ! important;" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT1PBMolDgRsyDXiehq5Fth6oECQZMCTQn_5cp8wL8sUPlOsjPM">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); "></div>

      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album five  </h3>


      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); height: auto; display: block;">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block ! important; float: left ! important;" src="http://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2015/03/17/102512937-498619551.600x400.jpg?v=1426619700">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block ! important; float: left ! important;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRx4DXyobeDy3Sw0n9Cm_cS6PGqPb-ivrT1DD4H9HReZRrOJQEk">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block ! important; float: left ! important;" src="http://joannagraham.github.io/img/pictures/8.jpg">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block ! important; float: left ! important;" src="http://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2016/12/08/104155736-5186314506_6882142ee7_o.600x400.jpg?v=1481234247">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); "></div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album Six  </h3>

      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album Seven</h3>
        <span class="cause-count">Albums (0)</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Album EIGHT </h3>

      </div>
    </a>
  </li>


  <!--item-->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simply assigning an image url randomly (maybe via for loop) to each image tag (within div/li), then let css handle how these images are designed

Comment: What I meant is that the way your images appeared should be controlled by the front end CSS and the way that you lay out your HTML divs. The reason for doing this is that it is a visual component. You want to assign classes to tags, or query for ".liClass img" so that you can control their content in this case being images. You can show images from any album that you want to your image tag source attribute through a for each function provided you have created an array of images from a database or folder.

Comment: And I don't mean to be vague however there is much to do in the background left for you to achieve this. You have to decide what is the default image - is it the first image posted into the database of the album stored? is it user defined? You will also need to figure out some sort of let's say algorithm on which four maximum or three minimum images are shown and how they are randomized in your grid, or what criteria determines images to be featured. This is more than just a jquery question, that's for sure.

Comment: I have tried different things but it is not working for all scenario's as show in example Image. Easy way to resolve it could be to add add two more container with 50% with & 100 height and keep 2 image in one and 1 image in other this can be swamped easily (randomly) to get different combination of design, `L1, L2 R3 | L1, R1, R2`

Comment: Can you share some of the things you have tried in code like a jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Is this going to be a consistent layout? Or will it need to adjust as more albums are added? Are the albums conatined always the same or will they be generated by a filter of sorts (i.e; date, rating, etc?)

Comment: Code sample is already there in question http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpmEmR

Comment: example which i have shown is basically a Categories of Album page where N number of Categories will be shown and each container for album can have minimum of 1 album & maximum of 4 album icons. logically if any category has just 1 album then it will show 1 icon which will occupy the whole category container otehr wise it can show 2,3,4 icons of albums in each category depending on how many albums that perticular category has let us assume we have football, cricket, skiing etc

Comment: From that i would query the database for the amount of albums so you know how many category containers you need,, then check the array within the album for the amount of pictures in it. If array is equal to or more than 4 than generate html with the appropriate containers with their reapective visual attributes with css classes. If array is less than 4 or equal to one generate html with only the one container again with the correaponding css class.

Comment: That part is already done i am stuck with design part and i think i have a solution for that. i have to add two more if i have more than 2 albums for each category and so on

Comment: the design should be driven by your array count based on conditional statements, each result generating a category container with a predetermined visual class for the predetermined layouts. 
Looks like you are on the right path, just start off with manual data first to figure out your design, once you like a certain configuration use that code with jQuery/javascript to generate it to the document as per the conditional statements I was mentioning.